# Canvas? or Canvas in the View.onDraw() method

Tags: android, kotlin, view, ondraw

Android Studio generates onDraw() method in the View class like this:

```
override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
    super.onDraw(canvas)
}
```

But in many samples from Google (Codelabs, courses etc) I see another version

```
override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas)
}
```

Which version is correct? And why?

Answer (score 1):

**fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?)**

This case canvas may be null. It accept null values so app may be crash null canvas object.so we have to handle nullability in all places.

**onDraw(canvas: Canvas)**

This case canvas must not null.so we don't care about nullability. we can avoid app crash so this is best one.

Comment: this explains what optional are, but doesn't explain why onDraws default parameter is an optional.